# Leaflet Custom Control Fails

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Why does the myMenu control not respond to a click?

```
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18, id: 'examples.map-i86knfo3' }).addTo(map);

    var myMenu = L.control({position: 'topleft'});
    myMenu.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'myMenu');
        this.update();
        return this._div;
        };

    myMenu.update = function () {
        this._div.innerHTML = "<h2>&equiv;</h2>" ;
        };

    L.DomEvent.on(myMenu, "click", function (e) {
        alert(50);
        L.DomEvent.stop(e);
        } )

    myMenu.addTo(map);
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but FA is a nice solution to a different problem, I believe.  What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get buttons displayed on your map, Leaflet has a plugin to attach a new control with a click event in one line: https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton

For help with coding, StackOverflow generally gets better responses. Since the question's already here though, this will get your control clickable:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

var myMenu = L.Control.extend({
  options: {position: 'topleft'},

  onAdd: function (map) {
          this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'myMenu');
          this._div.innerHTML = "<h2>&equiv;</h2>" ;
          L.DomEvent.on(this._div, "click", this._click )
          return this._div;          
  },

  _click: function(e){
    L.DomEvent.stop(e);
    alert(50)
  },

});

map.addControl(new myMenu());
```

By the way, clever use of `&equiv;`!

Comment: Perfect! That works so nicely, and answers the mail.  Will look harder for what you did right and I did wrong-O.  (BTW, thanks, but no claim here for originality in that three-bar icon usage.)

Comment: Got the initial problem sorted: The `myMenu._div` was only created `onAdd` so it didn't exist when the on `click` function was declared; it needs to be added after the control is added to the map. Also, the click event should be attached to the `myMenu._div` instead of the control object. Hope it helps!